# How call two asynch method in componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this two method in my App component, i will like use getLocation to set Latitude and Longitude and then i want call getWeather method. both method i will like to call in componentDidMounth

```
getLocation: function() {
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(       
      function(position){
       this.setState({
         location: position
      });
    }.bind(this)
  );
 }
}
```

and

```
  getWeather: function() {
    let latitude =48.1568806; //just for test
    let longitude =17.0739704; //just for test
    $.ajax({
      url:`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&APPID=${this.state.key}`,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({weather: data})
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(e){
      console.log(e);
    }

    });
  },
```

but i need wait for getLocation.

how can i handle this?

Comment: could you provide your code? there several ways how you can do it, with callbacks, with promises

Comment: Show us the functions!

Comment: So you want to call `getLocation` and when that is finished you want to start `getWeather`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass the location to `getWeather`, you can do it in the callback of `getLocation()`

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.getLocation();
}
getLocation: function() {
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(       
      function(position){
       this.setState({
         location: position
      });
      // Add call here, change getWeather to take a location object
      this.getWeather(location);

    }.bind(this)
  );
 }
}
```

A mored decoupled solution would be to use promises

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.getLocation().done(location=>{
      this.getWeather(location);
    });
},
getLocation: function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    if(navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        this.setState({location: position});
        resolve(location);    
      }.bind(this))
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
 }
}
```